# count the appearance of a small binary matrix in a big binary matrix

Tags: c++, algorithm, image-processing, matrix, bit-manipulation

given two binary matrices m1 and m2, m2 is guaranteed to have a larger or equal size (in both dimension) compared with m1.  write a function in C++ to count the appearance of m1 inside m2. 
e.g.

m1 = [1 1;1 1], m2 = [1 1 0 0;1 1 0 0; 0 0 1 1;0 0 1 1]

then m1 appeared in m2 2 times, the function should return integer 2.

Can anyone use a bit manipulation based method to solve this problem efficiently?

Comment: SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: Still waiting for the issue you are facing.

Comment: Any attempt done by you?

Comment: Start with brute force and nested loops comparing all possibilities and use the patterns you spot in the brute force solution to fine-tune your solution.

Comment: Yes, i would use bit tricks / manipulation to pack the data and perform more bit operations in parallel than possible using only some elementary type to store a single bit. Last time the speedup was about 300-fold.

Comment: I used brute force match with nested for loops first. This method works even if the matrix is not binary. But then I wondered if I could use bit tricks to make things run faster, and I got stuck because if I use bit manipulation based method, the size of the matrices are limited. And I wondered if there's any way to bypass this limitation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you represent your binary patterns with run-length encoding, the problem turns to an ordinary string matching one, on a compressed representation, and no bit fiddling required.

Then you can resort to a standard algorithm such as Boyer–Moore, and when a mismatch is found, you can use the longest shift among those found on all rows.

Comment: Intuitively, I thought about using bit tricks because the 2 matrices are binary matrices. But I then realize that simply converting the rows of the matrix to an unsigned long long integer has size limitation. Thanks for idea of string matching!